# how do I access navigation.toggleDrawer() from a stack navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a touchable icon in my stack header when I console.log({ navigation }) I get this:

```js
Object {
  "navigation": Object {
    "accessibilityLabel": undefined,
    "allowFontScaling": undefined,
    "backImage": undefined,
    "canGoBack": false,
    "label": undefined,
    "labelStyle": Array [
      undefined,
      undefined,
    ],
    "labelVisible": undefined,
    "onLabelLayout": [Function handleLeftLabelLayout],
    "onPress": undefined,
    "pressColorAndroid": undefined,
    "screenLayout": Object {
      "height": 667.2941284179688,
      "width": 338.8235168457031,
    },
    "tintColor": "#F5EDED",
    "titleLayout": Object {
      "height": 29.647058486938477,
      "width": 250.8235321044922,
    },
    "truncatedLabel": undefined,
  },
}
```

I have included my navigation code below starting with the drawer navigation.

```js
import React from "react";

import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs";

import MaterialCommunityIcons from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons";

import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";
import BodyPartsScreen from "../screens/BodyPartsScreen";
import PreMadeScreen from "../screens/PreMadeScreen";
import WorkoutDiaryScreen from "../screens/WorkoutDiaryScreen";
import StatsScreen from "../screens/StatsScreen";
import HistoryScreen from "../screens/HistoryScreen";
import ChestListScreen from "../screens/ChestListScreen";
import ExerciseSelectedScreen from "../screens/ExerciseSelectedScreen";
import StartWorkoutScreen from "../screens/StartWorkoutScreen";

import ContactSupportScreen from "../screens/ContactSupportScreen";
import FeatureRequestScreen from "../screens/FeatureRequestScreen";
import MeasurementsScreen from "../screens/MeasurementsScreen";
import MembershipScreen from "../screens/MembershipScreen";
import SettingsScreen from "../screens/SettingsScreen";
import DrawerContent from "../screens/DrawerContent";
import ProfileScreen from "../screens/ProfileScreen";



/////////////////////// Drawer //////////////////////////////////////////

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export const DrawerNavigator = (props, navigation) => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Back",
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
          },
        }}
      />

      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Membership"
        component={MembershipScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Membership",
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
          },
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileScreen}
        options={{
          title: "profile",
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
          },
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Measurements"
        component={MeasurementsScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Measurements",
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
          },
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Feature"
        component={FeatureRequestScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Feature Request",
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
          },
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Contact"
        component={ContactSupportScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Contact",
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
          },
        }}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Tabs Navigation.

```js
////////////////// Tabs /////////////////////////////

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

export function TabNavigator({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      activeColor="#D72323"
      barStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#000000" }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={DrawerNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Workout"
        component={StartWorkoutScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="weight-lifter"
              color={color}
              size={26}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Settings"
        component={SettingsScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="cog-outline"
              color={color}
              size={26}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Stack Navigation.

```js
////////////////////////// Stack /////////////////////////////////////

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export function StackNavigator(props, navigation) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#000000",
        },

        headerTintColor: "#F5EDED",
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: "bold",
        },
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="HomeScreen"
        component={TabNavigator}
        options={({ navigation }) => ({
          headerLeft: () => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
              name="forwardburger"
              color="#F5EDED"
              size={26}
            />
          ),
        })}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Drawer"
        component={DrawerContent}
        options={{
          title: "Drawer",
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Body"
        component={BodyPartsScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Body Parts",
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Diary"
        component={WorkoutDiaryScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Workout Diary",
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="PreMade"
        component={PreMadeScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Pre Made Workouts",
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Stats"
        component={StatsScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Your Workout Stats",
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="History"
        component={HistoryScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Your Workout History",
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Chest"
        component={ChestListScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Champion Chest",
        }}
      />

      <Stack.Screen
        name="ExerciseSelected"
        component={ExerciseSelectedScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Customise Your Exercise",
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

I need to get access to navigation.toggleDrawer() or navigation.openDrawer() how is this possible? I have the icon set in my stackNavigator not in the screen that I want to use it but it appears there.

Answer (score 0):

In the screen where you're setting your icon do this:

```js
    const StackNav = () => {
      return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Screen Name"
            component={ScreenComponent}
            options={({navigation}) => ({
              headerLeft: () => (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
                  <Icon name="menu" />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              ),
            })}
          />
        ...
        </Stack.Navigator>
      );
    };
```

Note that your `StackNav` component has to be the direct children of your `DrawerNavigator`.

### Edit

After analyzing your code I made a working Snack that demonstrates how to properly use the `DrawerNavigator`.

Note that I made some assumptions about what you're trying to achieve, but this is the usual way of how we setup navigation. Here's a link to the demo: [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@abdou-tech/navigation-demo).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I keep getting an error in the console saying . navigation.toggleDrawer is not a function. (in 'navigation.toggleDrawer(), 'navigation.toggleDrawer' is undefined) any ideas how to handle this?

Comment: @Ty87 This means that you're not receiving the `navigation` object of your `DrawerNavigator` maybe there's something wrong with the way you're using it. Could you modify your question and add the code of your `DrawerNavigator` and your `StackNavigator`?

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question to  include my full navigation code.

Comment: @Ty87 Yep your navigation setup is pretty messed up. Im not sure what you're trying to achieve exactly with the way you want your app to navigate, but there are some clear mistakes. Your `DrawerNavigator`should be the parent of all the other navigators, since you most probably want the user to be able to access the drawer from anywhere in the app.

Comment: @Ty87 In your current implementaion, `navigation.toggleDrawer()` is undefined because your `DrawerNavigator` is nested deep inside one of your `Stack.Screen`, so your `StackNavigator` has no way of accessing the `navigation` prop of your drawer since `props` are passed from parent to child, that's why your drawer should be in the top if you want all children to access it's props. I'll edit my answer and include a simple snack on how to use a `DrawerNavigator`.